# Return post values of form after submit

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony4

How to retrive values of posted form, for example in controller i check if is any username already if it redirect back to route which render the form, but how to retrive the last post values to not fill data of this form again.

example of controle:

```
    /**
 * @Route("/dystrybutor/pracownicy/add", name="dystrybutor_pracownicy_add")
 */

public function new(UserManagerInterface $userManager, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Request $request)
{


$pracownik = new Pracownik();
$form = $this->createForm(PracownikType::class, $pracownik);






    $form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $id = $this->getUser()->getDystrybutorId();

    $username = $form["username"]->getData();
    $password = $form["password"]->getData();
    $email = $form["email"]->getData();



    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $checkUser = $userManager->findUserByUsername($username);
    if($checkUser) {
                $this->addFlash(
                    'danger',
                    'Login jest już zajęty!'
            );

            return $this->redirectToRoute('dystrybutor_pracownicy_add');
    }
    else {
```

Comment: You seem to be doing things the hard way.  Most of the time you would not redirect on validation issues.  Maybe go over the examples in the docs again. https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#form-validation

Comment: Yes, i know there is possible to validate it a another ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you should just pass the *$pracownik* object to the action where you redirect to and then just pass it as argument when creating your form. This can be done with a lot of ways but I would suggest to use the [forward method](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/forwarding.html) in your controller:

```
public function new(UserManagerInterface $userManager, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Request $request, Pracownik $pracownik = null){

    $pracownik = $pracownik ?? new Pracownik();
    $form = $this->createForm(PracownikType::class, $pracownik);
    ...
    if($checkUser) {
        $this->addFlash('danger','Login jest już zajęty!');

        return $this->forward('App\Controller\DystrybutorController::new', array(
            'pracownik'  => $pracownik
        ));
    }
```

Comment: yeah, that`s greate. Exaclly what i need .... $pracownik = $pracownik ?? new Pracownik();